# Export .svg to .png without (any) antialiasing (`+antialias` doesn't work)

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to export [a svg file](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/plug_340755#term=power&page;=1&position;=67) to an icon sized .png. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to force ImageMagick to not to use antialiasing.

It seems to me that `+antialias` only turns off between colors aliasing but doesn't prevent to-alpha-channel aliasing.

I've tried:

- `convert +antialias -background none plug.svg -resize 32x32 plug.png`
- `convert +antialias -background none -size 32x32 plug.svg -resize 32x32 plug.png`
- Putting the `+antialias` keyword anywhere in the clause...

And all of them produce:

[image]

---

Imagemagics version: Version: `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2017-02-22`

Comment: What are you hoping it might produce?

Comment: @MarkSetchell A non-antialiased image. I.e. one with a one-bit alpha channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force ImageMagick to use 1-bit alpha channel, try using PNG-8 and set a better filtering algorithm such as Lanczos:

```
-filter Lanczos -resize 64x png8:result64px.png
```

This is an enlarged result with a 1-bit alpha channel:

[image: Magnified result]