# Converting PDF/SVG to PNG with antialias off using Magick++

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, magick++

I've tried to convert a SVG file to PNG with antialiasing off in Magick++ but I wasn't successful. But I was able to convert the SVG file to PDF with another program and the use the ImageMagick convert command to convert the PDF file to PNG.
How can I use ImageMagick to do it? The command I use for converting PDF to PNG is this:

```
convert +antialias -interpolate Nearest -filter point -resize 1000x1000 "img.pdf" PNG24:"filter.png"
```

Is there any way to use Magick++ to do that or better, convert SVG to PNG directly with antialiasing off?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

The answer given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491754/export-svg-to-png-without-any-antialiasing-antialias-doesnt-work) doesn't work for me. Possible because I'm using a colored SVG instead of 1-bit alpha channel. Also I mentioned in my question that I'm also looking for a way to do this in Magick++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export .svg to .png without (any) antialiasing (\`+antialias\` doesn't work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491754/export-svg-to-png-without-any-antialiasing-antialias-doesnt-work)

Comment: @ccprog Please read the question again because I've edited it. This question is different.

Comment: ImageMagick uses either Inkscape or librsvg for rendering SVGs, and has a fallback internal renderer. None of them offer control over antialiasing. In contrast, for PS/PDF import ghostscript is used, which has an appropriate option. (Note that the IM internal representation of images is pixel-based, so once it is imported, any damage is already done.)

Comment: @ccprog Thanks. I now just want to convert PDF to PNG using Magick++ (without antialias).

Answer (score 3):

Magick++ has the `Magick::Image::textAntiAlias` & `Magick::Image::strokeAntiAlias` methods available, but they would only be useful if your parsing the SVG and rebuilding the image (i.e. roll-your-own SVG engine) one SVG element at a time.

As @ccprog pointed out in the comments; once the decoder utility rasters the vectors, the damage is done & setting the flags would not have an effect on the resulting resize.

Without seeing the SVG, I can only speculate what the problem is. I would suggest setting the document *size* before reading the SVG content.

For example, read the image at a smaller size than resample up.

```cpp
Magick::Image img;
img.size(Magick::Geometry(100, 100)); // Decode to a small context
img.read("input.svg");
img.interpolate(Magick::NearestInterpolatePixel);
img.filterType(Magick::PointFilter);
img.resize(Magick::Geometry(600, 600));
img.write("PNG24:output@100x100.png");
```

[image: output @ 100x100]

Or render at larger size then the finial image.

```
Magick::Image img;
img.size(Magick::Geometry(1000, 1000)); // Decode to a larger context
img.read("input.svg");
img.interpolate(Magick::NearestInterpolatePixel);
img.filterType(Magick::PointFilter);
img.resize(Magick::Geometry(600, 600));
img.write("PNG24:output@1000x1000.png");
```

[image: output @ 1000x1000]

**Update from comments**

For Postscript (PDF) & True-Type antialiasing, you would set `Magick::Image::textAntiAlias` (or `Magick::Image::antiAlias` if using IM6) to false. Just ensure that the density is set to allow any overhead.

```
Magick::Image img;
img.density(Magick::Point(300));
if (MagickLibVersion < 0x700) {
    img.antiAlias(false);
} else {
    img.textAntiAlias(false);
}
img.interpolate(Magick::NearestInterpolatePixel);
img.filterType(Magick::PointFilter);
img.read("input.pdf");
img.resize(Magick::Geometry(1000, 1000));
img.write("PNG24:output.png");
```

Comment: But this generates new pixels (antialias) which I don't want it at all (not even one pixel). But I showed the command I use for converting PDF to PNG so it IS possible to do it with ImageMagick. How can I do it with Magick++ (PDF to PNG, antialias).